# Extraxt substring until "?" with sub()

Tags: r, data-manipulation

So, I want to extract the substring of a string like this
`mystr <- "aa/bb/cc?rest"`

I found the sub() function but executing `sub("?.*", "", mystr)` returns `""` instead of `"aa/bb/cc"`.

Why?

The reason is obviousyl because of `?` being a special character but using backticks or `"\?"` doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need double \ for escaping:

```
> mystr <- "aa/bb/cc?rest"
> sub("\?.*", "", mystr)
Error: '\?' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\?"
> sub("\\?.*", "", mystr)
[1] "aa/bb/cc"
```